# Visual Studio 2010 Wont Load Referenced DLLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, reference

I have been working on an ASP.NET project for months now without issue. Recently my computer crashed mid compile and now when I load and run the project I get 'Could not load file or assembly 'Ionic.Zip' or one of its dependencies.'

Thinking it was an issue with that particular DLL, I removed it as a test only to have the project say it could not load another referenced DLL, etc etc, until I had no references left...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything but NuGet, I didn't use it to get any of the references before.

In the end I had to check in all my changes to TFS, delete the project from my workspace and computer, and then reload it from TFS. Seems to have worked. Something must have been damaged in the project file.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing in the code has changed. "Build->Rebuild Solution" should do the trick (implicitly cleans and builds).

If this does not work, do "Build->Clean solution" and go delete all generated build folders (default bin and obj folders). And then try build and run.

And if it still does not work, the code has changed and dependencies are really missing.
Using NuGet and packages are missing perhaps?